# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencie

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, razorengine

This has been baffling me for ages and I just can't find the solution.

My MVC4 WebApp project used System.Web.Razor V2.

I am using the RazorEngine for some templates to use in emails, so when I pulled that in, it was looking for System.Web.Razor V3, so I removed the V2 and replaced with V3.

Now when I run the app, I get the "Could not load file or assembly" problem. Its still looking for V2.

I changed the reference in the  Website.csproj file to point to 3, cleaned down all folders.

I used a tool called Agent Ransack for searching all folders and files for any reference to 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0' and it comes back blank, there is no reference anywhere in the project directory for that file. Yet it still looks for it when I compile & run.

Here is the references section from my csproj file...

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\AutoMapper.3.1.1\lib\net40\AutoMapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper.Net4">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\AutoMapper.3.1.1\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Elmah">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\elmah.corelibrary.1.2.2\lib\Elmah.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\WindowsAzure.Storage.4.2.1\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\NLog.3.1.0.0\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PostSharp, Version=3.1.42.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b13fd38b8f9c99d7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\PostSharp.3.1.42\lib\net20\PostSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Device" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Spatial, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\System.Spatial.5.6.0\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
        <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\EntityFramework.6.0.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.1.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.0.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\WebMatrix.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\WebMatrix.WebData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.4.1.4.12333\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\..\dependencies\WebGrease.1.3.0\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I would guess that some of your other files like System.Web.Helpers might require version 2. you will need to upgrade them to version 3 also.